# How to convert timestamp into date/time string in PHP?

Tags: php, timestamp

I need to construct a [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) from an integer Unix timestamp `1329272833`. The documentation says the constructor needs a "date/time" string like `2006-04-12T12:30:00`. I manually did my own conversion:

```
$dateTimeEnd = new DateTime(
    date('Y-m-d\TH-i-s', 1329272833)
);
```

Does PHP have a built in function to do this conversion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a timestamp as parameter if you add the `@`-sign at the front:

```
$dateTimeEnd = new DateTime('@1329272833'); # 2012-02-15 02:27:13+00:00
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/4Sjf1g7L). You find it documented on [the manual page, see the examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php).

Answer (score 3):

```
$dateTimeEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', 1329272833);
```

See [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat)

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(1171502725);
```

[Datetime::setTimestamp()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php)

Answer (score 1):

All the comments above don't answer the question "how to convert timestamp to datetime STRING", they answer the question "how to convert timestamp to datetime OBJECT"

Given that $dateTime->date doesn't work, it seems to me the answer is not so obvious.

Probably

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(1171502725);
$date_string = date_format($date, 'U = Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

would be an answer.
Not sure it's optimal though. And looks ugly.